# Git: Undo checkout of files from different branch

Tags: git

So I was working on my Java project on Eclipse and I tried to checkout some files from a different branch like this

```
git checkout branch-name path-to-file/file-name
```

By mistake I checkout out an entire package

```
git checkout branch-name path-to-file
```

Is there a way to revert this change?

**Edit:**

I have a current branch A and another branch B.

I am working on branch A.

- Step 1: I make a commit on branch A.
- Step 2: Then I make some more
  changes on branch A.
- Step 3: I then accidentally checkout out another
  package from branch B, when in fact I only wanted to checkout a file
  from branch B, as I stated in the question.

I was wondering if I can just undo this accidental checkout so that I don't lose the changes made in **step 2**.

Comment: If your checkout worked, then probably you don't have uncommited changes. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I had uncommitted changes, why won't the checkout work?

Comment: Do you have any files staged currently?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, and these are mostly the files from that package i.e result of checkout. Few unstaged files as well, but these are the ones that are not a result of the checkout i.e changes I made before the checkout

Comment: Are you OK with wiping both the stage and working directory back to before the accidental checkout from another branch?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That is exactly what I want. To go back to the state before the accidental checkout.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have made the edits to explain the complete situation. Please take a look.

Comment: The answer is most likely no.  If you edited some file in branch `A`, but then overwrote that file with a checkout from `B`, _and_ you didn't stage that change (or stash, etc.), then the work is lost AFAIK.

Comment: If you are using a good IDE like IntelliJ then you might still have one option.  IntelliJ may have recorded the checkout from branch `B` as one editing action.  Simply doing CTRL+Z can bring back your previous file in many cases (I did this just today actually).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oh, great. I am using eclipse but Ctrl+Z is doing the job well. Thanks a lot for this, this would save a lot of time and effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

git checkout HEAD path-to-file

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete that local branch via

```
$ git branch -D <branch_name>
```

Since there's no undoing a branch checkout you can ditch the local copy of it. If you haven't made any changes you want to keep it's as simple as that.

In the event that you have made changes you want to keep, just stash your current changes and apply them to the branch you want them on. The syntax is straightforward:

Use this on the branch you want to eventually git rid of but want to save changes from.

```
$ git stash
```

Then, checkout the branch you want to apply the changes to and run the following.

```
$ git stash apply
```

Finally, you can delete the other local branch (the one you don't want) following the step listed above.

Comment: I don't think deleting a branch is what is asked for here. They modified their working copy and want to partially undo that.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I was answering the original question which was more ambiguous. The edits make it clearer. Good eye tho. Cheers.